# Using python client for Kubernetes I am not able to increase the number of replicas for a specific pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes, flask, amazon-eks

##### Details:

---

I am using AWS EKS service to manage my application in a K8 cluster.
In one of the pod which is called `my-core-pod` in the namespace `mytenantspace`, I have a python flask app running. I have created an endpoint `create_infra`, What it does is, it takes a POST request and increases the number of replica of pod `my-daemon-service-pod` in the namespace `myenvspace`.

Now I have the `kubectl` installed and the configuration are properly updated in the `.kube/config`.
I am using `python 3.8` and `kuberenets` client is `28.1.0`.

**Note:** I am able to connect and list all the pods and namespaces of the cluster using the python kubernetes client.

This is my implementation of increasing the replica pods.

```
#code running in the `my-core-pod` in the namespace `mytenantspace`
from  kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()



@app.route("/create_infra", methods=["POST"])
def create_pod():
    number_pods = 3
    pod_name = "my-daemon-service-pod"
    namespace = "myenvspace"

    # Get the existing pod's template.
    existing_pod = v1.read_namespaced_pod(pod_name, namespace)

    #Clear the resourceVersion to avoid the error.
    existing_pod.metadata.resource_version = None


    # Create new pods based on the existing pod's template.
    for i in range(number_pods):
        new_pod_name = f"{pod_name}-replica-{i}"
        new_pod = existing_pod
        new_pod.metadata.name = new_pod_name
        new_pod.metadata.uid = None  # Clear the UID to ensure a unique pod is created.

        # Create the new pod replica.
        v1.create_namespaced_pod(namespace, new_pod)
```

I am not getting any error. I am getting a huge response JSON in the console. But my pods are not scaling. Could you find the issue in my code, Am I using the right API ?

Comment: It seems like you're using bare Pods instead of Deployments, from your description?  I'd normally expect the Pods to be managed by a Deployment, and then your code would change the `replicas:` field of the Deployment and a new Pod would automatically be started (or stopped).  Kubernetes components like the HorizontalPodAutoscaler already work this way.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

---

```py
api_instance = client.AppsV1Api()
deployment = api_instance.read_namespaced_deployment(name=deployment_name, namespace=namespace)
        deployment.spec.replicas = number_pods
api_response = api_instance.replace_namespaced_deployment(name=deployment_name, namespace=namespace, body=deployment)
print("Deployment updated. status='%s'" % str(api_response.status))
```